# Using and Try/Catch blocks

Tags: vb.net, try-catch, using

I'm not very experienced with vb and have inherited an application from a previous programmer.  I was asked to run the Visual Studio analyse against the code to make changes as the application seemed to be causing memory issues. I got loads of messages about disposing of an object multiple times eg

*Warning    CA2202  Object 'myConnection' can be disposed more than once in method xxx'. To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object*

Simple, wrap it in a using block I thought. Then I discovered myConnection was used in a try/catch

```
JumpUpAgain:
Try
    myConnection.Open()
Catch ex As Exception
                LogIt("EXCEPTION", "Connection Error: " & ex.Message)
                myConnection.Close()
                SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()
                ConnectionString = Nothing
                conn = Nothing
                MySQLCmd = Nothing
                myConnection = Nothing

                Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)

                If ErrorLoopCounter = 5 Then
                    LogItDetail("Exception", "Database Connection Process failed after 5 re-tries")
                    If Not FailedFiles.Contains(InputFileName) Then FailedFiles.Add(InputFileName)
                    LogItDetail("DEBUG", "Added file to Failed Files for email")
                    FileProcessFailed = True
                    Throw
                Else
                    ErrorLoopCounter += 1
                End If
                GoTo JumpUpAgain

 End Try
```

And the myConnection object is required in later code.
I'll be taking out the myConnection=Nothing from the catch but if I put the using/end using outside of this try/catch block will it be disposed of correctly if the application hits the Throw?

Comment: Try looking at the [Using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement), it help with memory problems as it closes everything even if there's an exception.

Comment: Thanks the_lotus.  Seen similar but I think this is the key point

Comment: "A Using block behaves like a Try...Finally construction in which the Try block uses the resources and the Finally block disposes of them. Because of this, the Using block guarantees disposal of the resources, no matter how you exit the block. This is true even in the case of an unhandled exception, except for a StackOverflowException. "

Comment: @Cunning_as_a_fox  A Finally block only closes and disposes of objects if you write code to do so.

Comment: I think you could slow down everybody's day by using `,ClearAllPools()` Connection Pools are managed by ADO.net and should not be cleared just because your app has an error. A closed connection is returned to the pool.

Comment: Setting your objects to nothing does not free the memory and, more important with ADO objects, does not allow the object to release its unmanaged resources. Only the Dispose() method does that or hopefully the finalize when the GC eventually makes it rounds.

Comment: If you can, get rid of the GoTo. That has been out since the ninties.

Answer (score 0):

The Using blocks ensure that your db objects are closed and disposed (equally as important as closing) even if there is an error. You kind of have to fit in the Try Catch since variables defined inside blocks are not visible outside the block.

```
    Private Sub OPCode2()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        'Keep your connections local
        Using cn As New MySqlConnection("Your Connection String")
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select * From YourTable", cn)
                Try
                    cn.Open()
                    Using dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                        dt.Load(dr) 'or whatever you want to do with your connection
                    End Using
                Catch
                    'Your logging logic here
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```